# Create only non-duplicate records using SQL queries in Access-VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Issue detail: I have spent nearly two full days and I am still unable to find solution to this issue:

Step 1: I have a table named “table1”. It has three fields which are already populated. I created them using an insert SQL query from within VBA:

```
For n = 1 To .cbo_sbstRep Step 1 
    strsql = "INSERT INTO table1 (A, B, C ) " _
    & "Values (" & .cbo1 & "," & .cbo2 & "," & n & ")"  

    CurrentDb.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError
 Next n
```

This creates values in field C: 1, 2, 3

Step 2: Next, I am keeping the values of .cbo1 (corresponding field_A) and .cbo2 (corresponding field_B) same and just changing the input variable for field_C in table 1 using a combobox. Here, I changed it to 5.

I want the insert query to run again but do not insert record for values of 1, 2, & 3 as they already exist and instead just create values 4 and 5. The target table should have values in field C: 1,2,3,4,5 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your loop based on the last value already in the table. Something like this:

```
Dim start as Long

'get last value in column C, taking column A and B into consideration, and increment by 1
start = Nz(DMax("C","Table1", "A=" & .cbo1 & " and B=" & .cbo2), 0) + 1

If start >= .cbo_sbstRep Then

  For n = start To .cbo_sbstRep Step 1 
    strsql = "INSERT INTO table1 (A, B, C ) " _
    & "Values (" & .cbo1 & "," & .cbo2 & "," & n & ")"  

    CurrentDb.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError
  Next n

End If
```

This will only run if the combobox value is greater than the maximum value in column C, taking column A and B into consideration.

Since this is a many-to-many table you can set a composite primary key on all three fields `A, B and C` in table `table1`, disallowing any duplicates. This will guarantee your data consistency.

Comment: Actually, it won't work since, this is a joint table for many to many combinations where duplicates will exist. Also,  Dmax won't be helpful since the value also depends on other two columns.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your many-to-many requirement. Adding a filter on the DMax function.

Comment: I am sorry if I am unable to explain all the requirements in my first post. Actually, another issue is that sometimes, DMax will not be useful. Since the values can be 1,3,5 and 2, 4 are missing. In this case, if Combobox is 6 then my code should create 2,4,6.  Btw, I have found a solution to the issue. I want to share code here but it does not allow pasting. It is a long code and would be tedious to type here as it requires 5 queries and two loops.

Comment: @Lone You can answer your own question with the solution that you discovered. You should be able to put plenty of code in there.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt alright, I'll give it a try, if it works.

Comment: So, I tried copy pasting the code but the site does not allow. I tried inserting even image but the website kind of refused. Perhaps, it has to do with some privilege rights that I don't have at the moment.